# Perl JSON module | unable to get a JSON response

Tags: perl, json

I have a script that I am using to populate a JQgrid object.The following code that when executed from the CLI builds what appears to be a valid JSON query

```
#!/usr/bin/perl 
use CGI;
use DBI;
use JSON;
use Test::JSON;
use POSIX qw(ceil);
use strict;
use warnings;

my $cgi = CGI->new;
my $page = $cgi->param('page');
my $limit = $cgi->param('limit');
my $sidx = $cgi->param('sidx');
my $sordx = $cgi->param('sordx');

if(!$sidx) {$sidx = 1};
my $start = $limit*$page - $limit;

my $dbh = DBI->connect('dbi:mysql:hostname=localhost;database=test',"test","test") or die $DBI::errstr;
my $count = $dbh->selectrow_array("SELECT COUNT(id) AS count FROM test;");
my $sql = "SELECT ID, Name FROM test ORDER BY ? ? LIMIT ?, ?;";
my $sth = $dbh->prepare($sql) or die $dbh->errstr;

$sth->execute($sidx,$sordx,$start,$limit) or die $sth->errstr;
my $total_pages;
if( $count >0 ) {
        $total_pages = ceil($count/$limit);
} else {
        $total_pages = 0;
}
if ($page > $total_pages){ $page=$total_pages};
$start = $limit*$page - $limit;
my $i=0;
my $response = {};
$response->{page} = $page;
$response->{total} = $total_pages;
$response->{records} = $count;
        while (my $row = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
                my @arr = @{$row};
                $response->{rows}[$i]{id} = $row->[0];
                $response->{rows}[$i]{cell} = \@arr;
                $i++;
        }

Test::JSON::is_valid_json $response, '... json is well formed';

print $cgi->header(-type => "application/json", -charset => "utf-8");
print JSON::to_json($response,{ ascii => 1, pretty => 1 });
```

If I put the script into CGI debug mode, it returns the following (Note, manually edited to mask sensitive data):

```
{
   "page" : "1",
   "records" : "35",
   "rows" : [
      {
         "id" : "15675",
         "cell" : [
            "15675",
            "Test 1"
         ]
      },
      {
         "id" : "15676",
         "cell" : [
            "15676",
            "Test 2"
         ]
      }
   ],
   "total" : 4
}
```

Edit: I added Test::JSON package, and it gives me the following error:

> input was not valid JSON: malformed
>   JSON string, neither array, object,
>   number, string or atom, at character
>   offset 0 (before "(end of string)") at
>   /usr/lib/perl5/site_perl/5.8.8/JSON/Any.pm
>   line 571.

I'm not sure where to go next with this. Any other changes I make to the code will not put the appropriate brackets in place on the returned string.

Comment: Simplify your program to aid debugging. Does encoding this literal data structure work as expected? `print JSON::to_json({page => undef, records => 25, rows => [ { cell => [ 1, "1999-01-01", ( "0.00" ) x 3, "Notes with punctuation" ], id => 1 }, { cell => [ 2, "2001-01-10", 103.98, 45.34, 149.32, "This is record 1" ], id => 2 }, { cell => [ 3, "2001-02-10", 104.98, 46.34, 151.32, "This is record 2" ], id => 3 } ], total => 0 })`

Comment: Well, of course `Test::JSON::is_valid_json $response` tells you it's not valid JSON.  At that point, `$response` is the hashref _before_ it's encoded into JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing this string into `JSON::decode`, I see complaints about the literal newlines in the strings `"This is record 1"` and `"This is record 2"`. What if you convert them to `\n`?

```
foreach my $row ( @{$ref} ) {
    $response->{rows}[$i]{id} = @$row[0];
    $response->{rows}[$i]{cell} = $row;

    # escape newlines in database output
    s/\n/\\n/g for @{$response->{rows}[$i]{cell}};

    $i++;
}
```

(There's probably a more general and more robust way to do this)

Comment: I think the newlines were added when he pasted the JSON on SO.  The `to_json` function should be doing any necessary escaping automatically.

Comment: But then the JSON string should have literal `\n`s, not newlines in the middle of the quoted expression. When could the interpolation have taken place? Either (1) JSON::to_json didn't do it in the first place, (2) the CGI logger changed it, (3) the OP changed it when typing his question, or (4) it got changed on the OP's clipboard between copying and pasting to SO. Either way, what got posted is not a "valid JSON result".

Comment: I'm fairly sure they must have been added in 2, 3, or 4, because `to_json` shouldn't be producing invalid JSON.  So your answer won't fix the problem, because he hasn't explained what the problem is.